# Creating a series of images in one window using python where the user can scroll through the images

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have created a script which displays a series of images, each within their own respective figure:

```
fig  = plt.figure()
pylab.imshow(ds.pixel_array, cmap=pylab.gray())
plt.scatter(py,px, s = 10, c = 'r', marker = 'o')
plt.scatter(uy,ux, s = 10, c = 'y', marker = 'o')
plt.scatter(ry,rx, s = 10, c = 'm', marker = 'o')
plt.scatter(xcoord, ycoord, s=10, c = 'g', marker = 'o')
plt.title('back PLANE' + str(i))
plt.show()
```

this part of the script is all within a for loop so a new figure is created for each image. How do I go about putting all the images in one window which the user can then scroll through? I've lookd at subfig but all I can find is how to put all images inside one window.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [matplotlib sequence of figures in the same window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443474/matplotlib-sequence-of-figures-in-the-same-window)